# Win10 no-touch backups to synology nas

Tags: windows-10, backup

I have a Win 10 desktop and a new DS214play Synology NAS.  I have been backing up my desktop with Carbonite for years, but now I would like to set up the same functionality on my NAS (since it is set to glacier backup).  The key features I am looking for are:

- No-touch change syncing - like Google Drive/Carbonite/CrashPlan
- Client folder selection - On the client I want to be able specify existing folders, not limited to set folders like Google drive or Dropbox.
- Version tracking - I got bit by CryptoLocker a while back, and while it was able to encrypt my entire local backup drive, and all it's changes synced up to Carbonite, I was able to roll back all those changes.  The client needs to be able to write backups to the server, but not overwrite backups on the server (so mapping a drive to a drive letter is right out).

Any thoughts on windows clients (or system settings) that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Crashplan seems to suit your requirements. If I got them right:

- Client folder selection: yes. Crashplan lets you select specific
  folders on your hard drive: [example from my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA3hG.png)
- Automatic change sync: yes. CP monitors the changes in the selected folders and adds new/updated files to the backup.
- Version tracking: yes. CP has quite a flexible versioning, here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjhxW.png)

I'm using Crashplan to back up my laptop to WD NAS. What's needed to set it up:

1. Install CP app per user, not as a service (version >4.3 allows this).
2. Map a desired destination folder on your NAS to a drive letter so it's visible in Explorer and CP's destination selection dialog.

Another possible alternative: Genie Timeline. I used it for a couple of years, it has all the aforementioned features, but not as flexible (and not free).